Error on Github Desktop when trying to clone a repo
I get this error when I try to clone a repository I created on Github onto my local machine through Github Desktop:
fatal: could not create work tree dir '/Test_Keep_For_future': Read-only file system  Would you like to retry cloning ?
Any ideas why and how I could fix it?
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Github Desktop
